# Replace Symbol Keys in Object With Text

Tags: javascript, json, sequelize.js, stringify

I have the following object like this:

```
{ where: { [Symbol(or)]: [ [Object], [Object] ] },hooks: true, rejectOnEmpty: false }
```

I'm calling `JSON.stringify` on this, and it gets converted to:

```
{"where":{},"hooks":true,"rejectOnEmpty":false}
```

I think this is because `[Symbol(or)]` evaluates to undefined so `stringify` removes it.

This value is coming from `Sequelize` operators, specifically `Op.or`. Is there a way `stringify` can convert this to a String so I would instead receive:

```
{"where":{"[Symbol(or)]": [[<<stringifiedObject>>], [<<stringifiedObject>>]]},"hooks":true,"rejectOnEmpty":false}
```

I know I could pass a function to `JSON.stringify` which would replace `undefined` with something, but I would like to maintain the original Symbol in the string replacement, so that I can distinguish between `Symbol(and)` and `Symbol(or)`, even though both would evaluate to undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with the following function:

```
const cleanObject = (obj) => {
    try {
        const keys = Reflect.ownKeys(obj);
        const ret = {};
        keys.forEach((key) => {
            let val = obj[key];
            if (Object.prototype.toString.call(val) === '[object Object]') {
                val = cleanObject(val);
            }
            if (typeof key === 'symbol') {
                const newKey = `${String(key)}`;
                ret[newKey] = val;
            } else {
                ret[key] = val;
            }
        });
        return ret;
    } catch (ex) {
        console.log(ex);
    }
};
```

`Reflect.ownKeys` returns all keys, including `Symbols`.

Next, I check if a given key is a `Symbol` and replace it with a string. I also call the function recursively to apply the same logic to all nested objects.